# Appending iframe delays javascript animations

Tags: jquery, animation, iframe, embed, delay

I am building a lightbox, when it's opened I append an iframe (vimeo universal iframe embed code), but there is one other animation running, namely a description that slides out from the bottom of the screen.

At the moment of appending, everything seems to halt for a bit, probably due to the fact that the iframe is taking up all resources? Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

When I test without appending the iframe, (showing a black screen), everything runs smoothly. I need these animations to happen concurrently.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are auto playing the video on load, the best way is to load just an image instead of the video itself.

Here is an example of using the image and autoplay instead of loading the video: http://embedly.github.com/embedly-jquery/examples/autoplay.html

The code looks something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Replace the url with an image
    $(".video a").embedly({maxWidth: 500,
                       autoplay: true,
                       success : function(oembed, data){
                         //replace the a tag with an image
                         var d = $('<a href="#" class="play"><span></span></a>')
                              .css('background-image', 'url('+oembed.thumbnail_url+')')
                              .data('oembed', oembed);
                         data.node.replaceWith(d);
                       }
                    });
    // When the user clicks play the video is loaded inline.
    $('a.play').live('click', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).replaceWith($(this).data('oembed').html);
    });
  });
```